# Jenkins - Temporary Credentials \ Secret

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to create a temporary credential \ secret in jenkins that will live for the pipeline job only?

I have a function in my library that creates and returns (temp) sensitive information, and I want to prevent the possibility of other developers accidentally printing them to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to achive a good enough result by using something along the lines of:

```
password_mask += [password: secret_value]
...
wrap([$class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', varPasswordPairs: password_mask]){
        return closure.call()
}
```